# How to use if else in python launch file?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. Sorry for all mistakes, English is not my native language. I'm migrating my project to ROS2 Foxy. In my old launch file I have following lines of code:

```
  <arg name="config" default="$(eval 'cartographer_jetson.lua' if (target == 'jetson') else 'cartographer_host.lua')"/>
  <arg name="odom" default="$(eval '/rs_t265/odom/sample' if (target == 'jetson') else '/minicar/controller/odom')"/>
```

How those lines should look like in python launch file? I actually couldn't find documentation with examples that cover that situation, so if there are some documentation with detailed explanation of python launch file creation process I'll be would be very grateful for a link.
Appreciate any help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/409490/how-to-use-if-else-in-python-launch-file?/) by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2022-11-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are interested in these tutorials:

- https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Intermediate/Launch/Launch-Main.html

Especially usage of `from launch.conditions import IfCondition` from https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Intermediate/Launch/Using-Substitutions.html#substitutions-example-launch-file

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on 2022-11-17**:
Thank you for your help.

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-11-17**:
Please accept it as an answer, so it will have a chance to be moved to the StackExchange later :)